# Why do I have to reference components in start, but declare variables in no void?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

New to c# and unity. I am confused about why have to declare variables in a different place to referencing the components. I followed [a tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4180726-introduction-to-unity-scripting-part-1) to get here btw.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Sheep : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float runSpeed;
    public float gotHayDestroyDelay;
    private bool hitByHay;

    public float dropDestroyDelay;
    private Collider myCollider; // variables declared here
    private Rigidbody myRigidbody; // and here

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        myCollider = GetComponent<Collider>(); // but set here
        myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); // and here
    }

    // void Update and some more things here
}
```

Comment: By defining them as fields you can use  them in all the instance (not static) methods of the class.

Comment: In order to access those variables throughout your class, you need to scope them them to the class, not just the `Start`-method.

Comment: @HimBromBeere then why can't I do the `GetComponent` where I create the variables?

Comment: Vague answer: In the definition (private Collider myCollider) you can't say that its value is a GetComponent one, since GetComponent needs an object to work on, but it's not yet created when the definition is being *read. But in its declaration (myCollider = GetComponent) that object exists and the unity scene has started.

Comment: You can't call `GetComponent` at the class level because that is not allowed in C#.  All executable code must be inside a method in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a hybrid of newness to Unity as well as C# itself. Let's break it down:

### Inheritance

When you write a Unity script, you are usually writing a C# class. This class and all of its information is contained within the squirrely (curly) braces "{" and "}". However this class can also *inherit* from another class. Consider inheriting like using a template. Monobehaviour is a Unity-defined class that has a bunch of fields, properties, and methods already created like "Update()" "Start()" "gameObject", etc. When you inherit from MonoBehaviour, you are actually saying "use the MonoBehaviour template".

So the following code already has a lot of fields/methods available to it from the MonoBehaviour inheritance even when you haven't written any yourself:

```
public class NewScript : MonoBehaviour
{
}
```

### Class level fields

A field is what you see when you "declare" a variable:

```
float numA = 100;
```

As you can see in the above code, I can assign a value to the field when it is declared. This declaration happens as soon as the class is constructed. In this case, the assignment of the declared variable happens immediately on declaration. If I tried to declare my field with data from another class and the other class hasn't been constructed yet, it would fail.

### The Unity Engine and MonoBehaviour

Now that we've established that your class has things happening "under the covers" with MonoBehaviour and that class level field declarations happen immediately, we can get to the meat of things:

Here's a simplification of how a Unity program starts:

1. All GameObjects are created, their Components are initialized, and their scripts constructed.
2. All Components run Awake().
3. All Components run Start().
4. The game cycle begins (Update, FixedUpdate, LateUpdate, etc.).

Notice that some GameObjects and Components may be constructed before others. If you tried to call GetComponent on a GameObject before the other component is constructed, it would fail. This is why you are not able to call GetComponent during the constructor phase when your fields are declared.

### Alternative

Unity allows serialization of fields in a monobehaviour, exposing them in the inspector. You could instead write your field declarations with the [SerializeField] header (or make your fields publically accessible) and drag/drop the components into them in the inspector:

```
    [SerializeField] private Collider myCollider; // variables declared here
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody myRigidbody;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a class. When you declare a variable you are saying "A `Sheep` has this attribute," but you are not necessarily telling it what that attribute *is* or what the `Sheep` does with the attribute.

In the `Start()` function in Unity, you are giving the MonoBehaviour (the class from which your `Sheep` is derived; don't worry *too* much about how this works early on) instructions for what to do right when the object starts existing. In this case the first thing you do is find your collider and your rigidbody, so that in other functions (`Update()` for instance) you will know what `myCollider` and `myRigidbody` are.

Hopefully that helps. You said you were new so I tried my best to ELI5.